# How to use QVTKOpenGLWidget with proper hidpi

Tags: vtk, qvtkwidget, hidpi

When I try QVTKWidget， there are warning messages that told me donot use it.

So I change to QVTKOpenGLWidget.

But there are problems with this widget, it doesnot display properly. See the picture.
[image]

I use 
VTK 8.1.2

Qt 5.12.3

win10 + msvc2017x64

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution. But it is not perfect.
I develop my code with QtCreator, and because I use a 4K screen, I set QT_SCALE_FACTOR to 1.5.
If I set QT_SCALE_FACTOR to 2.0, the QVTKOpenGLWidget works fine.

So, the solution is set QT_SCALE_FACTOR to an integer.